# Data is not stored in flask sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Im creating a flask app and the data is not stored when i click register after adding all the information. when I click the register button there are no any errors showing.
heres my routes.py

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register_page():
 form = RegisterForm()
 if form.validate_on_submit():
    user_to_create = User(username=form.username.data,email=form.email.data,password_hash=form.password1.data)
                          
                
    db.session.add(user_to_create)
    db.session.commit()


    flash(f'Account created Successfully...! you are now logged in as {{ user_to_create.username }}',
          category='success')
    return redirect(url_for('topup_page'))

 if form.errors != {}:
    for error in form.errors.values():
        flash(f'There was an error with creating the user{error}', category='danger')

 return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

here is my register.html file

```
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="container">
      <form method="POST" class="form-register">
      <h2>Please Create Your Account</h2>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
      <br>
        {{ form.username.label()}}
        {{ form.username(class="form-control", placeholder="User Name")}}
        <br>
        {{ form.email.label()}}
        {{ form.email(class="form-control", placeholder="Email Address")}}
        <br>
        {{ form.password1.label()}}
        {{ form.password1(class="form-control", placeholder="Password")}}
        <br>
        {{ form.password2.label()}}
        {{ form.password2(class="form-control", placeholder="Confirm Password")}}
        <br>

        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary disabled") }}
        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
        <h6> Already have an account? <a  href="{{ url_for('login_page') }}"> Sign In</a>
        </h6>

    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

here is my models.py file

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
 return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
  username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
  email = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, unique=True)
  password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
  credit = db.relationship('Credit', backref='owner')
```

Comment: You can create a classmethod named add_user in your user model. And you can add users there. Also why you use RegisterForm() ? You can use if request.method == 'POST' and get your data over html input name. you can send this data to clasmethod later.

Comment: yeah but here i've used the flask forms to get the data. okay i will replace flask forms with the html form and try to get the data. somehow this might be a issue with the flask forms i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add a name attribute to the inputs. Sorry if this is a wrong answer.I have not used flask in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you sample code:

Template:

```
  <form  action="{{ url_for('app.update_view') }}" method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input name="name1" placeholder='abc'> 
        <input name="name2" placeholder='xyz'>
        <input name="name3" placeholder='123'>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button> 
    </form>
```

View:

```
@app.route('/path', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@roles_required('admin,member') # doenst matter
def update_view():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name1 = request.form.get('name1')
            name2 = request.form.get('name2')
            name3 = request.form.get('name3')
            if name1 is not None and name2 is not None:
                YourModelNAme.create_classmethod(name1, name2, name3)
        return render_template("directory_name/your_html.html")
    except Exception as e:
        return create_json_response(
            {'message': 'Error->' + e.__str__()}, False, 201), 201
```

Model:

```
class YourModelNAme(db.Model, UserMixin):
  name1 = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
  name2 = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
  name3 = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)


  @classmethod
  def create_classmethod(cls,name1,name2,name3):
    your_model = YourModelNAme()
    your_model.name1 = name1
    ...
    db.session.add(your_model)
    db.session.commit()
    return your_model
```

Comment: I have tried this and it working. thanks mate